# Entity Framework 6 error when adding a ContextDb Object

Tags: entity-framework

I have just added a WPF project to my app and when I try and use my DataAcccess class to interact with Entity DB I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded

This error has only started happening since I added this project and I cant figure it out. I copied over my App.Config to the new project, here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And the error is happening in one of my classes when trying to build a list of objects, in the line

> using (var context = new DataAccess())

:

```
namespace MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer
{
    public class Instrument
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Expiry { get; set; }
        public double TickSize { get; set; }
        public double TickValue { get; set; }
        public double OpenTime { get; set; }
        public double CloseTime { get; set; }

        public Instrument(string name, string expiry, double tickSize, double tickValue, double openTime, double closeTime)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Expiry = expiry;
            this.TickSize = tickSize;
            this.TickValue = TickValue;
            this.OpenTime = openTime;
            this.CloseTime = closeTime;
        }

        public static List<Instrument> GetAllInstruments()
        {
            List<Instrument> InstrumentList = new List<Instrument>();

            using (var context = new DataAccess())
            {
                foreach (var instrument in context.Instrument)
                {
                    InstrumentList.Add(instrument);
                }
            }

            return InstrumentList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you double check that the assembly (EntityFramework.SqlServer) that contains your ADO.NET provider (System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices) is deployed to the output folder (bin\debug)
It looks like assembly resolution mechanism cannot locate it
To view more details on assembly resolution errors you could use [Fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx)

By default, when you install the latest version of 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' as a NuGet package, you get both assemblies referenced from your project

- EntityFramework.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Double check that you have those references (and that they have copyLocal property set to true), and if not - re-install the package

Comment: I am not using ADO.Net, just entity framework 6, not sure why ADO is mentioned. I had a look at the tool you mentioned but nothing is listed in it. I also copied the app.config to the new project? where else should I check ?

Comment: Entity Framework is built on top of ADO.Net
As for Fuslogvw, you have to go to settings and enable the logging, it is off by default (on Win 10)
Your goal is to locate EntityFramework.SqlServer assembly, and get it to bin\debug folder
Make sure you have a reference from your project to that assembly

Answer (score 0):

try with add `connectionString` after `</configSections>`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Your_EntityName" connectionString="Data Source=your_server_name;Initial Catalog=Your_database_name;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help all.  I installed entity framework on the new project and now it works. I didn't realise that the new project would need it as the first project is handling the data.

Comment: yaah you need to install entity frame work it will add all the xml code for you in your appcofig